# webmatrix3: The column name is not valid. [ Node name (if any) = ,Column name = "test1"

Tags: sql

Есть простая таблица в бд с колонками

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но я не могу добавить почему-то сюда данные по квери:

```
INSERT INTO RequestSiteCleanUp (host, comment) VALUES ("test1","test2")
```

пишет ошибку:

```
The column name is not valid. [ Node name (if any) = ,Column name = test1 ]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

по гугленю пишет что я не взял в кавычки test1 надпись. А по факту ведь беру.

Comment: Ага, походу это типа MS Sql или Oracle, у них в двойных кавычках имена столбцов. В одинарных - данные

Comment: замените `"test1"` на `N'test1'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В T-SQL [строковые константы обрамляются вовсе не в двойные(`"`), а в одинарные(`'`) кавычки](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179899(v=sql.110).aspx).

Корректный запрос выглядит так:

```
INSERT INTO RequestSiteCleanUp(host, comment) VALUES ('test1', 'test2');
```